# Libgdx Screen Confusion

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Hello this is my first time posting on here and am relatively new to coding.  I've been playing around with java and libgdx for a month or two and I'm confused about one thing for screens.

If I have a GameScreen class that is active when playing the game, and then wanted to switch momentarily to another screen for inventory or a pause screen or something, if I make the game switch back to the game screen it seems everything resets and a new game starts.   What would be the correct way to make sure the screen reloads in the same state it was just in?

Comment: Also If I need to provide some more information or I wasn't clear please let me know.  Like I said this is my first time using this site and I'm new to coding so I'm not 100% sure if I'm asking my question correctly.  So feedback would be welcomed instead of just downvotes :D

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out and am stupid :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep a screen alive in the background such as you described, you need to make sure you separate your game initialization code so it is only called when you are starting a new level. There are a million ways you could do this. Here's an example:

```
public class MyGameScreen {

    public MyGameScreen (){
        //load textures and sounds here if you aren't managing them somewhere else.

        startNewGameRound();
    }

    @Override
    public void show (){
        //this is only for stuff you need to reset every time the screen comes back. 
        //Generally, you would undo stuff that you did in `hide()`.
    }

    public void startNewGameRound (){
        //Reset all your variables and reinitialize state for a new game round.
        //This is called in the constructor for first time setup, and then it 
        //can also be called by a button anywhere that starts a new round.
        //But do not load textures and sounds here. Do that in the constructor
        //so it only happens once.
    }

}
```

Then in your Game class, you also need to make sure you keep your game screen instance and reuse it.

Don't do this:

```
setScreen(new MyGameScreen());
```

Do this instead:

```
//member variable:
private MyGameScreen myGameScreen;

//In some method:
if (myGameScreen == null)
    myGameScreen = new MyGameScreen();
setScreen(myGameScreen);
```